# Javascript floating point addition giving wrong result

Tags: javascript

When I tried `0.1 + 0.2` in my JavaScript code, I'm getting the result `0.30000000000000004`. I was expecting `0.3` as the result. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Also, how can I work around this to get the result `0.3`?

Comment: I don't see a single integer in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited with inputs from Alnitak**

You have to specify the number of decimal places you want using the toFixed() method.
If you want only one decimal place, then try

```
var result = (0.1 + 0.2).toFixed(1);
```

This expression returns a string which represents the floating point number rounded to 1 decimal place.

Comment: This converts it to string.

Comment: really? But I have used this before, and didn't see it converting to string.

Comment: Please check it well... I checked again now...

Comment: Even bigger crime is calling `parseFloat` on numbers

Comment: You give `typeof parseFloat(0.1 + 0.2).toFixed(2)`, and it returns `"string"`

Comment: @mridula Thanks for you answer. I'm not a purist, so I'll take your answer. Besides, no one else is having a better solution anyway!

Comment: @Sparky that's because there is no "better solution".  It's just how numbers work in JS.  But IMHO this answer is still not worthy of acceptance because it's wrong on two counts.

Comment: 1.  it returns a `string` (that's actually OK, but it's a shame the OP didn't know that) 2.  it converts `0.1 + 0.2` (i.e. `0.3`) _into_ a string so it can then be passed to `parseFloat`, which then turns it _back_ into a `Number` on which `.toFixed()` is invoked.  The right answer should be "you cannot represent 0.3 as an exact number in a numeric variable, but if you call `(0.3).toFixed(n)` you can obtain a string _representing_ that number rounded to the desired number of decimal places."

Comment: @Alnitak, I understand that. Thanks. But this works for me, whether its a solution or a workaround. So I accepted the answer, hoping that it would help someone like me. No offense meant.